# Getting numbers from a matrix

Tags: c#

Hi my problem is I can't get the numbers with more than 2 digits from this matrix if anyone can help I would appriciate it here i my code :

```
Console.Write("x: ");
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("y: ");
int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int[,] arr = new int[x, y];
int[,] arr2 = new int[x, y];

Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        int randNUm = rand.Next(0, 20);
        arr[i, j] = randNUm;
        Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
        if (arr[i, j] >= 10)
        {
            arr2[i,j] = arr[i,j]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean that for numbers with less than 2 digits it works OK?

Comment: You will have to specify expected vs actual results, what you did to debug etc.

Comment: What do you mean by NUMBER do you refer to X or Y dimension specifier. Or do you refer to content at arr[i,j]

Comment: nope it doesn't my task for school is to take the 2 digit numbers from he matrix and post them after the matrix's  been printed like this
1  10
15 2
10
15

Comment: well my point is that after the matrix arr[i, j] has ben printed I just want to print again the numbers that only have 2 digits. This  can't figure out how to do.

Comment: Add A Console.Writeline  inside if for arr2[i,j]??

Comment: in the arr2[i, j] I'm copying the numbers with 2 digits I just can't figure put how to print them separetly

Comment: apomene I wa thinking the same but I have to firsst print the whole matrix then separetly to print the numbers with 2 digits

Comment: make a second loop over the elements of  arr2[i, j]

Comment: I will appriciate it if you show me how tried to do it I'm in a dead end ...

Comment: You don't really need `arr2`. Only makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have done your job, all it remains is to display the results. If
the task specifies that the printing must be done in 2 steps as you imply,
try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        int randNUm = rand.Next(0, 20);
        arr[i, j] = randNUm;
        Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
        if (arr[i, j] >= 10)
        {
            arr2[i,j] = arr[i,j]
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("---Proceeding to 2 digit numbers---");

for (int i = 0; i < arr2.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arr2.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write(arr2[i, j] + " ");
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** Consider what Henk comments and try to optimise your solution.